# Pandana not working with large dataset

Tags: python, geopandas, networkx, network-analysis

I am trying to use "pandana" for network analysis instead of "networkx". With 400000 rows of my dataset works but with 500000 does not (numbers are not precise). I have my nodes and edges ready (not from OSM). When I want to create pandana network with like this:

```
network = pandana.Network(nodes_proj['x'], nodes_proj['y'], 
                      edges_proj['u'], edges_proj['v'], edges_proj[['length']], twoway=True)
```

, it gets stuck with:

> Generating contraction hierarchies with 16 threads.
>
> Setting CH node vector of size 403173
>
> Setting CH edge vector of size 800002
>
> Range graph removed 800002 edges of 1600004

and nothing happens. But with a smaller dataset, it works fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you run out of memory?

Comment: My memory is Ok. I am suspicious of CPU even though my machine has 8 core CPU and when I track my resources I don't see any memory or CPU issue.